# Multiple Simultaneous API calls in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, stress-testing

I am trying to stress test my Endpoint which works with dapper that calls procedure and has a lot of validation. Idea is to know how it can handle like 1000 API calls that was sent at the same time.

Note that it is **Get** Endpoint

Any idea?

I tried using thread pool, but it would not run 1000 of them at the same time, also I thought about Task but it was same here, also for loop is not option with tasks or anything else, because there still will be the time difference between each method run.

Comment: Are we talking about a cloud service?

Comment: ^^ if so, you could also make test consumers and scale those up until your desired load is reached.

Comment: *"I tried using thread pool, but it would not run 1000 of them at the same time"* -- Try calling before `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 10)`, and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: what about this?        `int numberOfCalls = 1000;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCalls; i++)
        {
            // Create a new task and add it to the list
            tasks.Add(SendApiCallAsync());
        }

        // Wait for all tasks to complete
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: Would you do that on the same machine,  @VivekNuna ?

Comment: @VivekNuna comments are not suitable for posting multiple lines of code. The code is practically unreadable. You could consider posting [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746821/multiple-simultaneous-api-calls-in-c-sharp#comment135303211_76746821) as an answer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thank you, I completely agree with you, but I wasn’t 100% sure so I didn’t post this as an answer, I wanted OP to try it first

Comment: is it better to make stress tester application in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using dedicated load testing tools like [K6](https://k6.io/) or [Bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier).
You run all your infrastructure including the service/system you are tryng to test locally or in cloud and then run the load testing tools against your service.

PS: Bombardier might be easier if you just have to make quick HTTPGET endpoint calls